# how do I create two Canvas elements to always fill their horizontal half?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm working on a small GUI to compare two pictures.

So far it uses tkinter and some elements placed using .grid in rows 1 and 2; in row 3 I want to place two canvases that share 50-50 with the rest of the form.

I liked the easy way to get one canvas there as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
canv=Canvas(root, bg='#f0f0c0')
canv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to make this?

I tried somewhat extending the code I got with no result, searched the topic but found no answers

Comment: If you understand how `weight` option works, you should know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it led me to the right answer